# mapping a function over nested tibbles returns some tibbles with NA

Tags: r

I have a large data frame and when I apply the below code I get an NA result in tibble 5 (for the dput here with 100 observations). When I apply this over the whole data set 100,000 observations I get all of the tibbles as NA.

I cannot seem to find what is causing the data to return NAs in some of the tibbles.

Code:

```
library(tidyquant)
nested_portfolio_prices <- port_prices %>%
  group_by(mod_year) %>%
  nest(.key = "data") %>%
  mutate(portfolio_data = map(data, ~select(.x, cusip, date_ret, ret)),
         portfolio_returns = map(portfolio_data, ~tq_portfolio(
           data = .x,
           assets_col = cusip,
           returns_col = ret,
           col_rename = "returns"
         )))
nested_portfolio_prices$portfolio_returns
```

Data:

```
    port_prices <- structure(list(mod_year = c("July_2016_June_2017", "July_2006_June_2007", 
"July_2015_June_2016", "July_2007_June_2008", "July_2011_June_2012", 
"July_2015_June_2016", "July_2010_June_2011", "July_2007_June_2008", 
"July_2016_June_2017", "July_2007_June_2008", "July_2016_June_2017", 
"July_2012_June_2013", "July_2017_June_2018", "July_2006_June_2007", 
"July_2010_June_2011", "July_2012_June_2013", "July_2011_June_2012", 
"July_2014_June_2015", "July_2013_June_2014", "July_2012_June_2013", 
"July_2010_June_2011", "July_2015_June_2016", "July_2009_June_2010", 
"July_2011_June_2012", "July_2012_June_2013", "July_2011_June_2012", 
"July_2011_June_2012", "July_2015_June_2016", "July_2012_June_2013", 
"July_2009_June_2010", "July_2011_June_2012", "July_2014_June_2015", 
"July_2008_June_2009", "July_2007_June_2008", "July_2017_June_2018", 
"July_2014_June_2015", "July_2014_June_2015", "July_2011_June_2012", 
"July_2014_June_2015", "July_2016_June_2017", "July_2015_June_2016", 
"July_2016_June_2017", "July_2013_June_2014", "July_2008_June_2009", 
"July_2009_June_2010", "July_2010_June_2011", "July_2014_June_2015", 
"July_2008_June_2009", "July_2008_June_2009", "July_2010_June_2011", 
"July_2016_June_2017", "July_2007_June_2008", "July_2010_June_2011", 
"July_2013_June_2014", "July_2011_June_2012", "July_2014_June_2015", 
"July_2006_June_2007", "July_2007_June_2008", "July_2007_June_2008", 
"July_2011_June_2012", "July_2016_June_2017", "July_2006_June_2007", 
"July_2008_June_2009", "July_2010_June_2011", "July_2010_June_2011", 
"July_2006_June_2007", "July_2014_June_2015", "July_2008_June_2009", 
"July_2007_June_2008", "July_2009_June_2010", "July_2011_June_2012", 
"July_2007_June_2008", "July_2016_June_2017", "July_2007_June_2008", 
"July_2015_June_2016", "July_2011_June_2012", "July_2006_June_2007", 
"July_2010_June_2011", "July_2012_June_2013", "July_2016_June_2017", 
"July_2014_June_2015", "July_2007_June_2008", "July_2007_June_2008", 
"July_2009_June_2010", "July_2008_June_2009", "July_2012_June_2013", 
"July_2016_June_2017", "July_2006_June_2007", "July_2010_June_2011", 
"July_2007_June_2008", "July_2012_June_2013", "July_2009_June_2010", 
"July_2014_June_2015", "July_2011_June_2012", "July_2011_June_2012", 
"July_2007_June_2008", "July_2009_June_2010", "July_2007_June_2008", 
"July_2013_June_2014", "July_2015_June_2016"), cusip = c("62671710", 
"07373010", "12558180", "88731730", "74912110", "37555810", "20030N10", 
"G2414010", "23102110", "92826C83", "10922N10", "24736170", "G4883310", 
"50025510", "12673P10", "85590A40", "69076840", "88250810", "91301710", 
"02209S10", "69351T10", "87150310", "58933Y10", "02376R10", "G6543110", 
"26483E10", "26483E10", "74331510", "49456B10", "49456B10", "69076840", 
"89364110", "74144T10", "G4779110", "92553P20", "12621E10", "12558180", 
"G6543110", "12558180", "00737L10", "87150310", "01535110", "G6543110", 
"03251110", "03760410", "14313010", "12621E10", "17737610", "00790310", 
"98849810", "57978020", "G9782210", "20030N10", "08467070", "68268010", 
"12621E10", "88033G40", "17275R10", "88731730", "02376R10", "38463710", 
"85590A40", "G4883310", "G6543110", "50188920", "50025510", "06050510", 
"74144T10", "G2414010", "69076840", "02376R10", "G9782210", "90781810", 
"95810210", "58283910", "26483E10", "17123210", "69351T10", "68268010", 
"22207020", "25667710", "G3223R10", "17275R10", "G7665A10", "G4779110", 
"71270410", "71708110", "58933Y10", "80589M10", "17290810", "68268010", 
"92220P10", "40414L10", "69076840", "G6543110", "88731730", "28102010", 
"G2414010", "56357140", "87612E10"), date_ret = structure(c(17381, 
13833, 17242, 14372, NA, 17108, 15365, 14071, 17609, 14042, 17452, 
16111, 17876, 13892, 15177, 15952, 15621, 16799, 16505, 15889, 
15415, 17268, 14908, 15547, 15987, 15637, 15796, 17106, 15860, 
15093, 15812, 16618, 14575, 14327, 17767, 16820, 16626, 15811, 
16720, 17640, 17176, 17374, 16440, 14487, 14886, 15287, 16826, 
14649, 14587, 15476, 17570, 14250, 15328, 16342, 15663, 16660, 
13724, 14078, 14166, 15497, 17569, 13805, 14431, 15286, 15385, 
13766, 16727, 14592, 14106, 15022, 15838, 14264, 17499, 14104, 
17235, 15778, 13952, 15176, 15947, 17563, 16672, 14181, 14039, 
14945, 14732, 15889, 17406, 13740, 15352, 14167, 15957, 14903, 
16772, 15785, 15796, 14165, 15068, 14224, 16349, 17224), class = "Date"), 
    ret = c(0.00155759381595999, -0.000875105615705252, -0.000237129832385108, 
    0.0185934118926525, NA, -0.0103434007614851, 0.00727406656369567, 
    -0.0025189493317157, -0.0182075817137957, 0.0234113670885563, 
    -0.000496421940624714, -0.0139020709320903, -0.0206297431141138, 
    0.0122618675231934, 0.00596422469243407, 0.0219557154923677, 
    -0.0108856670558453, -0.0150824375450611, 0.00800677016377449, 
    0.00084609683835879, 0.00461317086592317, -0.011513170786202, 
    -0.00935324653983116, NA, 0.00160722085274756, -0.0130445640534163, 
    0.00131501024588943, -0.00761662237346172, -0.0112096015363932, 
    -0.0086715230718255, -0.034984327852726, 0.00118677981663495, 
    -0.0350377112627029, -0.0209561642259359, 0, -0.00801474507898092, 
    0.0129484310746193, 0.0447073318064213, -0.000238714463193901, 
    0, 0.00560221634805202, 0.0217440351843834, -0.070071280002594, 
    -0.0327479131519795, -0.0331215336918831, -0.0371998772025108, 
    0.0267579536885023, 0.0256470665335655, 0.00461360579356551, 
    0.0054472079500556, -0.0126631893217564, -0.0348387062549591, 
    0.0231795627623796, -0.0025237298104912, 0.00525627844035625, 
    0.0116085726767778, -0.0360360853374004, 0.00650554755702615, 
    0.0086538614705205, NA, 0.0095509709790349, -0.0313121154904365, 
    -0.0120284967124462, 0.0137202274054289, -0.000314373755827546, 
    -0.0146458493545651, 0.0012406047899276, -0.0023971782065928, 
    0.0274906530976296, 0.00706938654184341, NA, -0.0162822101265192, 
    0.0404461212456226, -0.0207553151994944, 0.000456162786576897, 
    0.00345336413010955, -0.0132903717458248, 0.0130105027928948, 
    -0.012478431686759, -0.0382457934319973, -0.0125886546447873, 
    -0.0148753765970469, -0.00414471002295613, 0.0312298554927111, 
    0.0289345514029264, 0, 0.00239598192274571, -0.00300423637963831, 
    -0.00271675200201571, -0.0669045522809029, 0.0124804880470037, 
    0.000978274154476821, -0.0123838623985648, -0.028199590742588, 
    -0.00760159641504288, 0.131664857268333, -0.00431848457083106, 
    -0.0571128614246845, 0.00217387988232076, 0.00601415615528822
    )), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:

Running the following:

```
nested_portfolio_prices <- port_prices %>%
  group_by(mod_year) %>%
  nest(.key = "data") %>%
  mutate(portfolio_data = map(data, ~select(.x, cusip, date_ret, ret))
  )

nested_portfolio_prices$portfolio_data
```

Gives;

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
   cusip    date_ret         ret
   <chr>    <date>         <dbl>
 1 74912110 NA          NA      
 2 69076840 2012-10-08  -0.0109 
 3 02376R10 2012-07-26  NA      
 4 26483E10 2012-10-24  -0.0130 
 5 26483E10 2013-04-01   0.00132
 6 69076840 2013-04-17  -0.0350 
 7 G6543110 2013-04-16   0.0447 
 8 68268010 2012-11-19   0.00526
 9 02376R10 2012-06-06  NA      
10 02376R10 2013-05-13  NA      
11 26483E10 2013-03-14   0.00345
12 69076840 2013-03-21  -0.0282 
13 G6543110 2013-04-01  -0.00760
```

However `tq_portfolio` from the `tidyquant` package should have converted these NAs to 0 - as per the `warnings()`. It seems to be the only tibble with NAs in.

Running this code (adding back in `tq_portfolio`)

```
nested_portfolio_prices <- port_prices %>%
  group_by(mod_year) %>%
  nest(.key = "data") %>%
  mutate(portfolio_data = map(data, ~select(.x, cusip, date_ret, ret)),
         portfolio_returns = map(portfolio_data, ~tq_portfolio(
           data = .x,
           assets_col = cusip,
           returns_col = ret,
           col_rename = "returns"   
  )))
```

And opening up the `warnings()`. Gives (first 5 warnings);

```
Warning messages:
1: In PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio(., weights = weights,  ... :
  NA's detected: filling NA's with zeros
2: In PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio(., weights = weights,  ... :
  NA's detected: filling NA's with zeros
3: In PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio(., weights = weights,  ... :
  NA's detected: filling NA's with zeros
4: In PerformanceAnalytics::Return.portfolio(., weights = weights,  ... :
  NA's detected: filling NA's with zeros
5: In xts(x = structure(list(`02376R10` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  ... :
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
```

Where warning 5 gives a different warning.

EDIT 2:

Running;

```
for(i in 1:12){
  print(
sum(is.na(nested_portfolio_prices$portfolio_data[[i]]))
)
}

[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 5
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

Shows where the error is. I think I just need to do some data cleaning before hand, however I still do not understand why the `returns` in tibble 5 do not get converted to 0 and that the structure is different

```
5: In xts(x = structure(list(`02376R10` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  ... :
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
```

Comment: Nested data frames are handy but difficult to debug. The 5th nested df is one that comes back `NA`. Pull just that data out and run `tq_portfolio` as you did in the `map` call: you get back `NA` with a warning "[1] NA
Warning message:
In xts(x = list(`02376R10` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'" I don't know enough about `tidyquant` to help debug the specific message, but I'd recommend starting there

Comment: Thanks! I just found this out to (See edit). These should have been converted also `0` but never were.

Comment: I don't see a warning or mention in docs implying that on version 0.5.6. But if cleanup is necessary, it's probably safer to do that yourself instead of relying on something a function might automate for you

Comment: I have been cleaning myself, removing NA values, setting `returns` with NA to `0` etc. Yet the problem still remains.